# Logstash Multiline Logfile XML Parsing Filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I am absolutely new to Logstash and I am trying to parse my multiline logentries, that are in the following format

`<log level="INFO" time="Wed May 03 08:25:03 CEST 2017" timel="1493792703368" host="host">
    <msg><![CDATA[Method=GET URL=http://localhost (Vers=[Version], Param1=[param1], Param2=[param1]) Result(Content-Length=[22222], Content-Type=[text/xml; charset=utf-8]) Status=200 Times=TISP:1098/CSI:-/Me:1/Total:1099]]>
    </msg>
</log>`

Do you know how to implement the filter in logstash config to be able to index the following fields in elasticsearch

time, host, Vers, Param1, Param2, TISP

Thank you very much

Comment: Use multiline codec on input, then xml filter with xpath.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out how to do it. This is my pipeline.conf file and it works

```
input {
        beats {
                port => 5044
        }
}

filter {
        xml {
                store_xml => false
                source => "message"
                xpath => [
                 "/log/@level", "level",
                 "/log/@time", "time",
                 "/log/@timel", "unixtime",
                 "/log/@host", "host_org",
                 "/log/@msg", "msg",
                 "/log/msg/text()","msg_txt"
                ]
        }

        grok {
                break_on_match => false
                match => ["msg_txt", "Param1=\[(?<param1>-?\w+)\]"]
                match => ["msg_txt", "Param2=\[(?<param2>-?\w+)\]"]
                match => ["msg_txt", "Vers=\[(?<vers>-?\d+\.\d+)\]"]
                match => ["msg_txt", "TISP:(?<tisp>-?\d+)"]
                match => [unixtime, "(?<customTime>-?\d+)"]
        }
        if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
                drop { }
        }

        mutate {
                convert => { "tisp" => "integer" }
        }

        date {
                match => [ "customTime", "UNIX_MS"]
                target => "@timestamp"
        }
        if "_dateparsefailure" in [tags] {
                drop { }
        }



}

output {
        elasticsearch {
                hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
                user => user
                password => passwd
        }
}
```